# Fetching particular data from <table> (using Id) in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

View:

```
<td>
 <div class="template-demo">
  <button type="button" onclick="location.href=' {{ route ('SupAd.View_PL_Accnt/{$id}') }}'"  class="btn btn-outline-info btn-icon-text">
   <i class="ti-search btn-icon-append"></i>View
  </button> 
 </td>
```

Route:

```
`Route::get('View_PL_Accnt', [SupAdController::class, 'View_PL_Accnt'])->name('SupAd.View_PL_Accnt/{$id}');`
```

Controller:

```
public function View_PL_Accnt(Request $request){
    $id = $request->id;
    $data = User::find($id);
    return view('dashboards.SupAd.pages.index.View_PL_Accnt', compact (['data', 'id']));
 }
```

View_PL_Accnt.blade.php :

```
<h3 class="SupAd_name">{{ data['name'] }}</h3>
```

Error:

Use of undefined constant data - assumed 'data' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) (View: C:\Users\CuatrosMarias\Documents\GitHub\IPS\resources\views\dashboards\SupAd\pages\index\View_PL_Accnt.blade.php)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbAZb.png)

Comment: Post the code instead of screenshots.

Comment: in your view Accnt.blade.php you did mistake you forgot to use `$` in data variable use `{{ $data['name'] }}`

Comment: My bad but i already change it and a new error occured it says: Trying to access array offset on value of type null

Comment: can you show us what `dd($data)` shows in your Acct.blade.php

Comment: Check my edited answer. the result of eloquent is object so you need to use object syntax instead of array syntax.

Comment: return view('dashboards.SupAd.pages.index.View_PL_Accnt',['data'=> $data,'id' => $id]);
you need to update this line

Comment: I also tried this one return view('dashboards.SupAd.pages.index.View_PL_Accnt',['data'=> $data]);
But I got this error: Trying to access array offset on value of type null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

View:

```
<button type="button" onclick="location.href='  {{ route ('SupAd.View_PL_Accnt', [$user->id]) }}'"  class="btn btn-outline-info btn-icon-text">
 <i class="ti-search btn-icon-append"></i>View
 </button>
```

Route:

```
 Route::get('View_PL_Accnt/{id}', [SupAdController::class, 'View_PL_Accnt'])->name('SupAd.View_PL_Accnt');
```

Controller:

```
public function View_PL_Accnt($id){
    $data = User::find($id);
    return view('dashboards.SupAd.pages.index.View_PL_Accnt', compact (['data', 'id']));
```

View_PL_Accnt.blade.php :

```
 <h3 class="SupAd_name">{{ $data->name }}</h3>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to send variables using `with()` in your controller

```
    return view('dashboards.SupAd.pages.index.View_PL_Accnt')->with('data',$data)->with('id',$id);
```

Your View `Accnt.blade.php` you have used data as constant you need to use it as variable

Eloquent result gives object so you can access the name property of your result object like below

```
{{ $data->name }}
```

Comment: I also tried this  return view('dashboards.SupAd.pages.index.View_PL_Accnt')->with('data',$data)->with('id',$id); 
but still my error is: Trying to access array offset on value of type null

Comment: The {{ $data->name}} still doesn't work it says : Trying to get property 'name' of non-object

Comment: pls show what `dd($data)` results in your blade

Comment: dd($data) showing it on my blade it says null

Comment: I tried writing this on my view button 
 <button type="button" onclick="location.href=' {{ route ('SupAd.View_PL_Accnt/{{$user->id}}') }}'"  class="btn btn-outline-info btn-icon-text">
   <i class="ti-search btn-icon-append"></i>View
  </button>

But I got error : syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ')'

Comment: you dont need to declare `{{ }}` in `{{ }}` . `{{ route ('SupAd.View_PL_Accnt/ '.$user->id) }}`  use like this

Comment: OMG thanks that works!! hehe but I got another error it says: Route [SupAd.View_PL_Accnt/3] not defined. 

But my code in web.php is this : Route::get('View_PL_Accnt', [SupAdController::class, 'View_PL_Accnt'])->name('SupAd.View_PL_Accnt/{$id}');

Comment: @user18742698 If my solution helped you . you can mark it right :) Thank you. I hope another error is also solved

Answer (score 0):

typo error `{{ $data['name'] }}` `$` is missing at the view

Comment: My bad but i already change it and a new error occured it says: Trying to access array offset on value of type null

Answer (score 0):

Try this one works fine in my side always..

> ->with(compact('data', 'id'));